# Razor - Radio Button To Be Checked in a Foreach Loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, radio-button, checked

I have a radio button in a foreach loop within a form to be posted. I want the first one to be checked when they are listed. `checked = "checked"` below doesn't help. It only works if there is a  single radio button.

```
<form action="/logged/hotel" method="post" >
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.companies)
    {
       <input type="radio" name="graph" value="@item.Value" checked="checked" /> @item.Text<br />
    }
    <input type="submit" value ="LOG IN" />
</form>
```

Comment: what you mean **checked = "checked" below doesn't help.**, radio button not checked or what?

Comment: None of them is checked

Comment: `ViewBag.companies` not is empty?

Comment: No! If the loop creates a single radio button it's displayed as checked. But if two or more, none of them is being checked.

Comment: hm, i try your code and last radiobutton always checked

Comment: Is it? What am I doing wrong then? This is MVC 3. What version do you have?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43133/discussion-between-grundy-and-jude)

Comment: Before post question under MVC, try to study a little of HTML, you can't select more than 1 radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Add name attribute, this will group your radio buttons together and only displayed one as checked.

Comment: Radio button already got a name attribute. Talking about different one?

Answer (score 0):

Only one radio button in a set can be checked.
all your radio buttons are in the same set.
you want to put them each in a different set so say

```
name="@item.Value"
```

However MVC wont like that, so you will have to do something like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyGraphPage(GraphViewModel vm){
    foreach(var company in MyDataContext.Companies){
        if(Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains(company.Value){
            //show the graph
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the first one to be checked you can do this, its not the most elegant solution, but works.

```
<form action="/logged/hotel" method="post" >
@{
var isfirst = true;
}
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.companies)
    {
      if (isfirst) {
        isfirst = false;
        <input type="radio" name="graph" value="@item.Value" checked="checked" />@item.Text<br/>
      } else {
        <input type="radio" name="graph" value="@item.Value"/>@item.Text<br/>
      }
    }
    <input type="submit" value ="LOG IN" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @{
        bool isFirstChecked = false;
        foreach (var item in ViewBag.companies)
        {
            <input @(isFirstChecked ? "" : "checked") type="radio" name="graph" value="@item.Value" checked="checked" />
             @item.Text
            <br />
            isFirstChecked = true;
        }

     }
```